# Password Prompt using For Loop (C++)

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am having a small problem in my code from a practice problem in Jumping into C++ by Alex Allain using a For Loop below.

**Code Below**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string password;
    for ( int i = 5; i>=0; i-- ) {
        cout << "Please enter your password you have " << i << " attempts remaining: ";
        cin >> password;
    }
    if ( password == "Kent" ) {
        cout << " Password is correct.";
        break;
    } else {
        i--;
        cout << i << " attempts remaining." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error at the break statement below in the build messages {using CodeBlocks}

```
C:\Users\Documents\Jumping into C++\src\practice 4 (chapter 5 
variant).cpp|23|error: name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping 
[-fpermissive]|
```

I have done this same exact code using a while loop without a problem but when I use a For Loop the compiler goes on a witch hunt.. any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You seem to put your `break` statement outside the `for` loop. So, what shall it break?

Comment: Fix the indentation. Is all the code you expected to be in the `for` loop actually inside it? What did you expect the scope of `i` to be?

Comment: I think the main problem is the `}` after `cin >> password;`

Comment: you doing that `for(int i=5;..){  } if(){}else{ i-- }'`, when it should `int i` declare and used in same scope as `for(int i=5;...){  if(){}else{ i--; }  }`
simply

Comment: move the if/else inside the loop.

Comment: If you had the correct indentation (which Eziz just fixed) you probably would have seen the mistake right away.  The scope of your `for` loop should encompass the `if...else` block, and remove the `i--` from the `else` since it's already in your loop conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! I see my indentation was the issue... something so small I didn't catch. Spent a good bit of time staring at my screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put if-else inside the for loop:

```
for ( int i = 5; i>=0; i-- ) {
    cout << "Please enter your password you have " << i << " attempts remaining: ";
    cin >> password;

    if ( password == "Kent" ) {
        cout << " Password is correct.";
        break;
    } else {
        cout << i-1 << " attempts remaining." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also no need to decrement `i` in the `else` block since it's being decremented in the loop conditions.

Comment: @JustinRandall, tnx, changed.